# Can i retry a call in response of an http call using interceptor without use of catchError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-http-interceptors

In angular 6 When iam calling a http service using interceptor if i got a response 
{"status":403,"message":"Error in getting data try again"}

i want to recall the service again.
It is possible with catchError ,is there any other way to do it without catchError that is, i cant do it with error code . I want to do it with my status codes in response body

Following code when call success200 method, calling request again not working.its working only in catchError

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
    const authService = this.injector.get(UserTokenService);

    return next.handle(this.addToken(req, authService.getToken())).pipe(
        tap(
            event => 
            {   
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                return this.success200(req, next,event.body);
              }
            },
            error => status = 'failed'
          ),

          catchError(error => {
     //This will work
    return next.handle(this.addToken(req,  authService.getToken()));
        })

        );
}






//All Success request comes here
success200(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler,response){
    const authService = this.injector.get(UserTokenService);
    const routerService = this.injector.get(Router);

    if(response.status=="403"){
      //this call not working

      return next.handle(this.addToken(req,authService.getToken()));
    }

    else{

        return;
    }

}

addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {

    //req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
    if(token != null) {
    //set token header with all request
        return req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: token }});
    }
    else {
        return req;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoy about [retry](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) operator. For example:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
  const authService = this.injector.get(UserTokenService);

  return next.handle(this.addToken(req, authService.getToken())).pipe(
    flatMap(
        event => 
        {   
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return this.success200(req, next,event.body);
          }
          else {
            return throwError('Failed');
          }
        }
      ),
      retry(1)  // if you want to invoke 'next.handle' 1 additional time
  );
}
```

*I haven't tested this code but this is a general idea, you can see an example in the provided link below.*

I have created [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jycvkc) stackblitz example for you to see `retry` in action.

**UPDATE:**

I did some additional research and found out that whenever *403* error occurs on *http* call, you will automatically enter the `catch` block. I created another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sumd6z) example where you can see what happens on *http* requests for *200* and *403* responses. As for you example, you can also try something like this:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {
  const authService = this.injector.get(UserTokenService);

  return next.handle(this.addToken(req, authService.getToken())).pipe(
    flatMap(
        event => 
        {
           if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              return this.success200(req, next,event.body);
           }
        }
      ),
      catchError(e => {
        console.log('Failed attempt to login');
        return throwError('Failed');  // retry logic should automatically kick in whenever _throwError_ occurs
      }),
      retry(1)  // if you want 1 additional time
  );
}
```